# How do I call a function in my controller from a button in my .cshtml-page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, view, controller

I'm trying to create a dashboard/graphical interface for managing purposes. How can I create buttons that call certain functions from a controller? It's in ASP.NET CORE 3, using the MVC-pattern.

What I want to do in the application is executing c# code by calling a method from my Index.cshtml page and passing parameters.

I've tried multiple solutions, namely those that state that the view and controller are synced with the controller function looking for the "equally named" view but it just doesn't work.

**Edit: Found the solution: I needed to specify both the controller and ActionResult.**

```
<form action="Home/Change" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="DoorID" placeholder="Guid.." />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Post" />
        </form>
```

I was apparently not smart enough to read the countless tutorials.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please share your code, even if it doesn't work. We'd like to see the controller action you're trying to hit and the razor/javascript/ajax you're using in the view.

Comment: Just edited the post to show the code, got the solution now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send a piece of data after the button click to the server, you should create a form in your view and a post action in your controller. However, if you don't want to post any data and you want to simply do something after button click, creat a get action in your controller and navigate to that action path using button click event. Finally, you can return the same page at your action and do what you want before hand.
Use `[httpGet("path")]` attribute on top of any public function in your controller to Mark it as action. Then you can invoke it in HTML using something like this `<a asp-action="path">sth</a>`

Comment: I just found the solution I was looking for, but this should work as well since I tried doing it with the ButtonClickEvent a few days earlier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

since you only wants to trigger a function on a btn click and pass some data i recommend you to make an ajax call  to the back-end using java script or jquery is the more effective way.
it will look like this

```js
$('#btn').click(function () {
  $.post( "your action url ", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } )
  .done(function(data)
  {
   // in case your action return some data it will be in the "data" variable 
  });
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <!-- you need to have jquery -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
 <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
 <input type="button" id="btn" value="click me ">
</body>

</html>
```